# Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log' not found in Checkout

Tags: fatal-error

My checkout page is giving me this error:

Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /home/internat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage.php on line 98

What could be the problem? The error line is just the last line.

```
public function getAddressesHtmlSelect($address, $type)
{
    if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
        $options = array();
        foreach ($this->getCustomer()->getAddresses() as $a) {
            $options[] = array(
                'value'=>$a->getId(),
                'label'=>$a->getStreet(-1).', '.$a->getCity().', '.$a->getRegion().' '.$a->getPostcode(),
            );
        }

        $addressId = $address->getId();
        if (empty($addressId)) {
            if ($type=='billing') {
                $address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress();
            } else {
                $address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryShippingAddress();
            }
            if ($address) {
                $addressId = $address->getId();
            }
        }

        $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
            ->setName($type.'_address_id')
            ->setId($type.'-address-select')
            ->setExtraParams('onchange="'.$type.'.newAddress(!this.value)"')
            ->setValue($addressId)
            ->setOptions($options);

        $select->addOption('', 'New Address');

        return $select->getHtml();
    }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: [magento class zend log not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345003/magento-class-zend-log-not-found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error simply says, Magento couldn't find `Zend_Log` class inside your application. By default, this class resides in `\lib\Zend\Log.php`<sup>1</sup>. So the first thing that you want to make sure is, this class exist in your magento instance.

But the bigger mistake that I can see here is, there is a ***Core Hack***, which you should never do in Magento. If you want to extend Magento functionality, you should either do a rewrite or if possible, use an event handler.

In this case, default `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage` class do not have a method `getAddressesHtmlSelect()`, but it's parent class (`Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract`) has one. So I doubt someone is trying to modify it's parent class method behaviour by directly putting the method inside `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage`. This is completely wrong.

I am enforcing the point. "*In order to do this, you should either use any event handler or rewrite the class `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage`*".

**Note :** We can't see any `Zend_Log` class usage in the provided code. So further help is not possible, if you didn't provide more details.

---

<sup>1</sup> - [Zend Log class](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Zend/Log.php)